# How to checkout specific sub directory from gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab

My gitlab repo size is 20GB. I need to checkout only a specific sub directory from the gitlab repo. How I can do this. I do not want to clone the entire 20G gitlab repo as I just want to work on a subdirectory (200 MB) in size.

Thanks
Niraj

I tried git sparsh-checkout, but for that also we need to clone the repository (objects) and it's hogging the disk space.

Comment: Here is an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934

Comment: Did you try with git clone --filter=blob:none <repository-url>?  [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

Comment: @MrJami Thanks for the above solution. But I see two problems with the solution provide above.

1- I am not able to see the entire history logs for any file as we used --depth=1

2- I have a subdirctory called scr recursively under multiple dir/subdirs. So when I checkout it create a copy of all the availble scr available on my repository instead of a specific one.